# Does Button have property to store a string?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Does `Windows.Form.Button` have some property that can be used to store a `string`?

Thanks.

Comment: All controls have a Tag property where you can store anything you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`Tag` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
myButton.Tag = "Foo";
```

// ... later

```
string tagInfo = (string)myButton.Tag;
```

Comment: Most handy "on the go" property of any `Control` imo.

Comment: Didn't know it existed. Thanks.